# theme installation not working

Tags: themes

i am trying to install the divi theme.but its not working issue something like this

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/web2/wp-admin/includes/update.php on line 139

Comment: Hello! When you say you're trying to install the divi theme can you be more specific? There are several ways to install themes that work in different ways. Are you saying you downloaded the divi theme as a zip file and are trying to use the uploader? Or that you're using the point and click UI in the Admin interface to install Divi? Or did you try to download and extract Divi into place on the filesystem and activate it? Have you confirmed your local server can access the internet?

Answer (score 0):

[This error](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/update.php) is generated after a failed call to [`wp_remote_get`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/). In other words, WordPress is trying to retrieve a file from somewhere and doesn't get it, either because the server doesn't respond or the file doesn't exist. The problem may be with the remote server, or your own server's [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is not properly configured, causing the connection to be refused.